# ui-bootstrap datetime-picker define show-meridian to false

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [ui-bootstrap-datetime-picker](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker) with angularJS. And i'd like to know if it's possible to set show-meridian options of time-picker directly inside timepickerOptions ?

```
  ...  
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
       datetime-picker="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
       timepickerOptions="{'show-meridian': 'false'}"
       ng-model="ctrl.date.value" 
       is-open="ctrl.date.showFlag"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
...
```

This is a [`plnkr`](https://plnkr.co/edit/EB8MBAWgK7dEN8IfJLZn?p=preview) which illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the problem is wrong naming style. To make your code work, you have to change camel-case to dash-delimited: `timepicker-options` instead of `timepickerOptions` (see my [forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lla2javiyHUdiohporzN?p=preview)):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
   datetime-picker="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
   timepicker-options="{'show-meridian': false}"
   ng-model="ctrl.date.value" 
   is-open="ctrl.date.showFlag"/>
```

The key point here is [normalization process](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) being done by AngularJS. Since HTML is case-insensitive, AngularJS cannot convert HTML attribute named `timepickerOptions` into scope variable `timepickerOptions` - because `timepickerOptions` in HTML is seen by AngularJS exactly like `timepickeroptions`; so, there is no chance for it to determine how to normalize this name. Thus, you should always use `-`, `_` or `:` to delimiter different words in directive name when using HTML.